# How to fix bundler not finding Rails inside docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, dockerfile, containers

I'm trying to run [Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) inside a Docker container and getting an error.

After running

```
docker-compose up --build
```

it builds but then I get an error

```
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with bundle install
```

What am I doing wrong?

This is the error in my terminal:

```
Building blazer_app
Step 1/11 : FROM ruby:2.7-slim
 ---> b913dc62d63c
Step 2/11 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential ruby-full ruby-dev libpq-dev nodejs git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cd104b8b0995
Step 3/11 : RUN mkdir /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 408c4379fd33
Step 4/11 : WORKDIR /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9523180b9dfb
Step 5/11 : RUN git clone https://github.com/ankane/blazer /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 74d20e03d0b4
Step 6/11 : ENV BUNDLE_PATH /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c8baefb8b45e
Step 7/11 : ENV GEM_PATH /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ca3230326184
Step 8/11 : ENV GEM_HOME /blazer
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe6dd938bc16
Step 9/11 : RUN gem install bundler
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 92614a0a968b
Step 10/11 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 87ef51235e08
Step 11/11 : CMD bundle exec rails s -p 1000 -b '0.0.0.0'
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 3dbf4d438d4b

Successfully built 3dbf4d438d4b
Successfully tagged blazer_blazer_app:latest
Starting blazer_postgres ... done
Starting blazer_web      ... done
Attaching to blazer_postgres, blazer_web
blazer_postgres | 
blazer_postgres | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
blazer_postgres | 
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.883 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.2.0) 9.2.0, 64-bit
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.883 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.883 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.898 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.925 UTC [20] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-02-02 20:31:12 UTC
blazer_postgres | 2020-02-02 20:31:14.929 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
blazer_web    | bundler: command not found: rails
blazer_web    | Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
blazer_web exited with code 127
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  blazer_db:
    container_name: blazer_postgres
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - blazer_db_vol:/blazer_postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - bridge_net

  blazer_app:
    container_name: blazer_web
    build: .
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://postgres@db:5432/postgres" # app database
      BLAZER_DATABASE_URL: "postgres://dbuser:dbpass@dbhost:5432/dbname" # target database
    volumes:
      - blazer_app_vol:/blazer
    networks:
      - bridge_net
    depends_on:
      - blazer_db

networks:
  bridge_net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  blazer_db_vol:
  blazer_app_vol:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7-slim
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential ruby-full ruby-dev libpq-dev nodejs git

RUN mkdir /blazer
WORKDIR /blazer
RUN git clone https://github.com/ankane/blazer /blazer

ENV BUNDLE_PATH /blazer
ENV GEM_PATH /blazer
ENV GEM_HOME /blazer

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

CMD bundle exec rails s -p 1000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile please - it looks like rails isn't included there

Comment: @Mark I only have `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile `. The rest of the files are from Blazer: https://github.com/ankane/blazer/blob/master/Gemfile & https://github.com/ankane/blazer/blob/master/blazer.gemspec

Answer (score 0):

That repository does not include Rails.

I think you want to check the [installation details](https://github.com/ankane/blazer-dev#install) in the [Blazer dev project](https://github.com/ankane/blazer-dev).

Comment: what's the difference between Blazer and Blazer Dev?

Comment: Please provide a summary of the pertinent information in the links in the answer itself, and supply an attribution to the author of it. Links rot then break, and when they do your answer will be useless. See "[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/153968)"

and "[Link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)"

Answer (score 0):

They author of Blazer created a new project for Blazer Docker: https://github.com/ankane/blazer-docker